# VB.Net/Access SQL insertion sub query issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I am making a form that can be filled in and will execute a insertion query with a button.  I do not know how to reference another table within this block of code.  I am trying to insert the Name, Phone Number, and Email within the form along with the corresponding Distributor ID.  The only way to get the Distributor ID is to reference the Distributor table.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    provider = 0
    dataFile = 0
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "XXXXXXX.mdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

    '*THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA*'
    Dim str As String
    str = "INSERT INTO [Distributor Contact] ([Name], [Phone Number], [Email], [Distributor ID]) VALUES(?,?,?,?) WHERE [Distributor ID] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Distributor ID] FROM [Distributor] WHERE [Distributor Name]= '" & ComboBox_Dist.SelectedItem.ToString() & "'))"

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Name", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Phone Number", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
    Me.Refresh()

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()

        MsgBox("Contact Added")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    myConnection.Close()

    'RE-POPULATE COMBOBOX
    ComboBox_Dist.Items.Clear()
    Dim connString1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= XXXXXXXXX.mdb"
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString1)
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM [Distributor Contact];"

    cmd2 = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2)

        adapter.Fill(dt)

        'Add Items To ComboBox
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            ComboBox_Dist.Items.Add(row(1))
        Next
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the final working code for anyone in the future.

```
    provider = 0
    dataFile = 0
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "XXXXXXXX.mdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    Dim str As String
    str = "INSERT INTO [Distributor Contact] ([Contact Name], [Phone Number], [Email], [Distributor ID])"
    str += "SELECT ?,?,?,[Distributor].[Distributor ID]"
    str += "FROM [Distributor] WHERE [Distributor].[Distributor Name] = ?"

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Contact Name", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Phone Number", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Distributor Name", ComboBox_Dist.SelectedItem.ToString()))

    Me.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the ComboBox_Dist as a parameter and then use a Select instead of Values for your insertion query.  The select allows you to reference the Distributor table.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("DistributorName", ComboBox_Dist.SelectedItem.ToString()))

str = "INSERT INTO [Distributor Contact] ([Name], [Phone Number], [Email], [Distributor ID]) "
str += "SELECT ?,?,?, [Distributor].[DistributorID] "
str += "FROM [Distributor] WHERE [Distributor].[Distributor Name] = ?"
```

Comment: Hmmm.... I made the changes and I am now getting an error on the new ComboBox_Dist Parameter line.  Error Message: "No value given for one or more required parameters. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Sounds like ComboBox_Dist.SelectedItem is null/nothing.  You'll have to validate it has a value before running that code.

Comment: I was able to validate via MsgBox that ComboBox_Dist.SelectedItem.ToString() is properly holding a value.

Comment: Did you keep those other parameters too?  I cut off the first two because I didn't want to paste in all of your code.

Comment: Yes, I kept them included.

Comment: From what I'm finding in search results with OLEDB with that error, it can be caused by one of the column names not being right (like a typo).

Comment: Missed a space in the SQL. Thank you so much!